# Finding the entropy

Tags: dynamical-systems, entropy, morse-theory, compact-manifolds, gradient-flows

Let $M$ be a compact manifold and $F:M\to \mathbb{R}$ Morse function. Let $\phi_t$ be a flow generated by $F$ in the following way: $\frac{d\phi _t}{dt}=-\nabla F(\phi _t)$. Let $f=\phi _1$. Find $h(f)$, where $h$ is (topological) entropy of $f$.

I thought I should use the following: Morse function on compact manifold has finite number of critical points. But this means that there is a finite number of $t$-s and $x$-s such that $-\nabla F(\phi _t(x))=0$. This just gives me that : $\frac{d\phi _t}{dt}=0$ in finite number of points and I don't know what to do with this.

Comment: I don’t know much about dynamical systems, but can’t you use the fact that every trajectory must converge to a critical point of the function (which are finitely many)?

Comment: @Mindlack That might be useful but I can't see how. It's very hard for me to find a connection between any of these things and entropy. It also appears to me that all of the possibly useful facts I can think of say something about functions when $t$ is changing and here I have that $t=1$ is fixed.

Comment: Yes, but the entropy considers powers of $f$ with arbitrary large exponents, corresponding to long-term behavior of the flow. Besides, you also have it in the reverse (ie in $t \rightarrow -\infty$, $\phi_t$ also converges pointwise).

Comment: Isn't it obvious that the entropy is zero? What else could it be?

Comment: The dimension of the manifold? Its inverse? The sum of the indices of critical points? The sum of the inverses of all three, multiplied by the best Lipschitz constant for $F$? If it is so obvious that the entropy is zero (something which seems, indeed, the most natural answer), please provide a proof or a sketch.

Comment: @Mindlack It seems that you have no idea about what is a gradient system and what is entropy. Good luck! :)

Comment: @John B: Indeed, my knowledge of what entropy is is mostly from Wikipedia’s definition. My knowledge of gradient systems is maybe less limited, but isn’t anywhere near a “working knowledge”. I know barely enough to know that my suggestions in my previous comment really aren’t likely candidates for entropy. That doesn’t necessarily mean that zero is the only one; that doesn’t mean either that there is any simple proof that such is the entropy. If you have a sketch of proof or some insight to share, I at least (and probably the OP) would be delighted. Thank you for wishing me luck anyway. :)

Comment: In the meantime I've stumbled upon an alternative definition of entropy and I think that one might be easier to work with here. I assume the solution can be obtained from what @Mindlack first said and this alt definition, although I haven't really solved this problem yet. Anyway, it's nice to know what I'm looking for. Of course, I would still appreciate the proof :D

Comment: @Mindlack From my point of view, it would be more effective if only "experts" intervene in each topic. In this case the question is obviously an exercise (in fact a trivial one) and what is important is that the student thinks of it by himself/herself and reaches somewhere. Note that I have noted several students of mine asking trivial things here... Anyways, I am curious to known what is your "proof" since you think that you can intervene in the topic. :D